# Non-null parameter when changing theme from Notification Shade

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

Whenever I use the Notification Shade to switch between the device dark and light themes, (my app when running) always seems to crash for some reason. My app's minimum API is 29 (Android 10). The logcat points to a line of code where the reason for the error isn't obvious. (`import android.view.*`). How can I prevent this from happening again?

> ```
>  java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter view
> ```

**Activity class**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.detail_container, MainFragment())
            .commitNow()
    }
}
```

**Main fragment class**

```
package com.example.vp2

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.*
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.core.app.NavUtils
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import java.util.*

class MainFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mySpinnerItems: Array<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        return v
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val mSpinner = requireView().findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.mSpinner)
        val mViewPager2 = requireView().findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.mViewPager2)

        // Spinner items array
        mySpinnerItems = arrayOf(
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
        )

        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireView().context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mySpinnerItems)
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
   
        mSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                when {
                    mySpinnerItems[position] == "Item 1" -> {
                        mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(0, false)
                    }

                    mySpinnerItems[position] == "Item 2" -> {
                        mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(1, false)
                    }

                    else -> {
                        mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(2, false)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(0, false)
            }
        }
        mSpinner.adapter = arrayAdapter

        mViewPager2.adapter = MySpinnerFragmentAdapter(this)
        mViewPager2.orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL

        mViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                when (position) {
                    0 -> {
                        mSpinner.setSelection(0)
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        mSpinner.setSelection(1)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        mSpinner.setSelection(2)
                    }
                }
                super.onPageSelected(position)
            }
        })

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }

    private class MySpinnerFragmentAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
        private val intItems = 3

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> Fragment1()
                1 -> Fragment2()
                else -> Fragment3()
            }
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return intItems
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        menu.clear()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
            val intent = activity?.let { NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(it) }
            when {
                intent != null -> {
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
                    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(requireActivity(), intent)
                }
            }
            true
        } else super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

**Main activity layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main fragment layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/detail_container">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/mViewPager2"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <!-- divider (start)-->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
    <!-- divider (end)-->

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mSpinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

**cactustictacs' suggestion**

```
    mSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            when {
                mySpinnerItems[position] == "Item 1" -> {
                    mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(0, false)
                }

                mySpinnerItems[position] == "Item 2" -> {
                    mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(1, false)
                }

                else -> {
                    mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(2, false)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
            // Code to perform some action when nothing is selected
            mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(0, false)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace (please post the actual text in future not a screenshot!) is saying some parameter called `view` is null when its type is specified as non-null (`View` instead of `View?`). And that's being caused by `AdapterView.onItemSelected` running (so it's the `view` parameter in that method), which is declared in `onActivityCreated`

Basically that `onItemSelected` method needs to have nullable types for the first two parameters, `AdapterView<*>?` and `View?`.

That's what you get if you let the IDE auto-implement the methods (with ctrl+I) - [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener#onitemselected) have that `View!` type which means because it's coming from Java, it could be null, might not, don't know - so the safe default is `View?`. When you specify a non-null type (like `View`) Kotlin does a null check to make sure - that's what that `Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter` call is. You got a null, so it threw an exception!

So yeah, make them nullable, then null-check them before you access them. Also make sure `appcompat` is up to date (at least `1.2.0`) because they had an issue where `Activity`s weren't being recreated when you [used `setDefaultNightMode`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.2.0-rc02)

Comment: For the null checking part, would this code go before the `when` clause? Would I check if they're null at the same time?

Comment: There's a few ways to check for nulls and handle them safely (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) but in this case, because it's a parameter, it's a ``val`` and won't change - so you could just do a ``if (view == null) return`` line at the top. Because the compiler knows that you'll only continue in the method if the value is non-null, and the value can't change (and become null), it "smart casts" it to a non-null type for the rest of the function anyway. But you're not actually using ``view`` in your code, so you don't need to check it at all! Just make the type nullable

Comment: Problem solved. I didn't include it all based on your suggestion. No point in having useless code. Many thanks.